# How to compile libunity for Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, autogen

I am trying to compile `libunity` obtained from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~unity-team/libunity/trunk). But `autogen.sh` fails 
with this message:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh
checking for automake >= 1.11.2...
  testing automake... found 1.14.1
checking for autoreconf >= 2.53...
  testing autoreconf... found 2.69
checking for intltool >= 0.25...
  testing intltoolize... found 0.50.2
checking for pkg-config >= 0.14.0...
  testing pkg-config... found 0.28
Checking for required M4 macros...
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments.
If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
`./autogen.sh' command line.

Processing ./configure.ac
Running intltoolize...
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --warnings=no-portability
configure.ac:4: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.ac:4: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
extras/Makefile.am:99: error: HAVE_INTROSPECTION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
src/Makefile.am:171: error: HAVE_INTROSPECTION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

searching the google yields no useful results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package gobject-introspection.

Possibly some other packages will be missing after that (as I experienced when compiling nemo/nautilus): search with "apt-cache search MISSING-LIB" and select the development library package (ending by -dev).

Comment: The source where I found the solution for gobject-introspection: https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/184

Comment: I hope you solved your issue in the meantime, but hopefully the answer will be useful for others.